# Use .net framework assembly in .net framework targeted class library from .net 7 console app

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following setup:

`.net 7 console app` calls `.net fwk 4.8 class library` calls `.net fwk 4.6.2 vendor DLL`

The vendor DLL does something like:

`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3`

Please don't ask why, it's stupid, but they won't change it...

Anyway this works when running it from .net framework 4.x but it throws a
`NotSupportedException: The requested security protocol is not supported.`
when the code is called from my .net 7 console app because of different checks being performed in `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ValidateSecurityProtocol()` ([Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/ServicePointManager.cs,48c3cfdf156ccd85))

Now I'm trying to somehow make the class library load the System assembly from .net framework instead of .net core. Is that even possible?

I was thinking of maybe:

- Using binding redirects? (but the assembly structure is totally different)
- Create a separate app domain to load .net framework assemblies into?
- Inject another ServicePointManager via DI? (but private ctor and no point to inject I guess...)

Comment: "Now I'm trying to somehow make the class library load the System assembly from .net framework instead of .net core. Is that even possible?" No, basically. The System assembly (and similar ones) are tightly coupled with the runtime.

Comment: Certificates have an encryption mode.  TLS 1.2 and 1.3 are only valid TLS versions.  Some encryption modes  will work only with 1.2, others only with 1.3, and some with both.  See  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security

Comment: ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 is a static setting.  So you can override with : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl2 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3

Comment: @JonSkeet I was hoping for some possibility for class libraries targeting another framework version, but anyway thanks for providing some detail

Comment: @jdweng Yes I can override it afterwards, but the vendor library will set it to SSL3 in any case and right there the exception is thrown no matter what...

Comment: Why can't you use a certificate that support TLS 1.3?  Vendor is setting TLS to 1.3.  You are probably failing because the certificate being used doesn't support TLS 1.3.

Comment: I can but that's not the problem. The vendor will not change their DLL which enables SSL3, so this will always result in an exception when runtime is >net4.x ... :(

Comment: I would be worried by a vendor requiring a basically obsolete protocol. If you can possibly move to a different vendor, I would do so. Who knows what else they'll refuse to update, leaving security problems etc.